# How to stop a user from clicking anywhere on the screen during session activity

Tags: c#, click

I am writing an automation application where a program is opened and while that program is opened I don't want the user to be allowed to click anywhere on the screen as that will cause the automation to possibly fail at specific points.I have not been able to find anyone who has a solution to this, most of the solutions only provide answers for buttons or specific windows, but I want to disable the mouse click entirely for the user. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not easily no... Aside from writing a new mouse driver. Maybe disable the mouse? Like through Device Manager or by uninstalling the driver? Why don't you run the automation under a different context, if the user shouldn't interact with it anyway, why run it interactively atall?

Comment: @Milney the automation opens a third party application that requires interactivity in some form, which is given by keyboard and mouse clicks by the automation, however I don't want the user to be able to remove focus from the application running by clicking anywhere on the screen or in the app as to ruin the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a global mouse hook

Use a global mouse hook to monitor and optionally block mouse events.

An example implementation of global mouse/keyboard hook is [MouseKeyHook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook/) nuget package and the GitHub source code [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook).

#### Blocking only user clicks

If you want to prevent the user from clicking but keep sending automation clicks, you can raise a flag to signal to the mouse down event not to block the next click.

***Note: There is a small chance that in the small amount of time from when the flag was raised until the event filters the next mouse down, a user click will be captured by the hook instead of the automation click.***

#### Blocking mouse down events example

In the following code, I give an example of using [MouseKeyHook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook/) nuget package to prevent mouse clicks globally for a `TimeSpan` amount of time:

Required using declarations:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
```

Code:

```cs
// Global hook
private IKeyboardMouseEvents _globalHook;

// Stopwatch to count the amount of time the global mouse down events are blocked
private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// The amount of time to block global mouse down events
private TimeSpan _timeSpan;

// Attach global hook
private void Subscribe()
{
    _globalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
    _globalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
}

// Remove global hook
private void Unsubscribe()
{
    _globalHook.MouseDownExt -= GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
    _globalHook.Dispose();
}

// Global hook mouse down event 
private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
{
    if(_stopwatch.IsRunning)
    {
        if(_stopwatch.Elapsed < _timeSpan)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }
}

// Block global mouse down events for timeSpan amount of time
private void BlockMouseDown(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    _timeSpan = timeSpan;
    _stopwatch.Restart();
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// Attach global hook
Subscribe();

...

// Block mouse down event for 10 seconds
BlockMouseDown(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: ...and if a global mouse hook is in place preventing activity, how will the automation work correctly?  How will it distinguish between what is from the user, and what is from the automation program?

Comment: You can raise a flag to signal to the mouse down event not to block the next click. There is probably almost no chance that in the small amount of time from when the flag was raised until the event filters the next mouse down that the user will click the mouse.

Comment: "There is probably almost no chance that in the small amount of time from when the flag was raised until the event filters the next mouse down that the user will click the mouse."  You have no idea when the next mouse click from the user will occur.  This will fail at some point; the real world has a way of proving itself better at breaking things than we think.  ;)

Comment: For instance, I had a student complain once that their login screen wasn't responding to mouse clicks correctly.  Turns out they moved things on the table around and a book was ever so slightly holding the space bar down.  This would be quite a problem with a keyboard hook.  It happens...

Comment: @Idle_Mind: I guess you are write. It may still work for most cases. Anyway, I added a note warning about the problem